# How to get value properly from form field?

Tags: 8, forms

I search the best way to get value from  form field, and I would like to know if my code section below it's the only way to get value from field (`$value = $var[0]['value']`) or if it's possible to write this better:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function my_module_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id){
  if ($form_id == 'node_bibliographie_form') {

    $form['#validate'][] = 'node_bibliographie_form_validate';

    foreach (array_keys($form['actions']) as $action) {
      if ($action != 'preview' && isset($form['actions'][$action]['#type']) && $form['actions'][$action]['#type'] === 'submit') {
       $form['actions'][$action]['#submit'][] = 'my_module_bibliographie_form_submit';
      }
    }
  }
}

function my_module_bibliographie_form_submit(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state){
  // Get the submitted entity.
  $key        = $form_state->getValue('field_key');
  $id_dossier = $form_state->getValue('field_dossier_reference');

  if (isset($id_dossier) && isset($key) &&  !empty($key) && !empty($id_dossier)) {
    kint($id_dossier[0]['target_id']);
    //ugly ?
    $collection_key = $key[0]['value'];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If  you need to get the value of the array you can use below method.

```
 $values = $form_state->getValue(array('name_of the array', 'key'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting fine the value, but I see that you can improve the use of `isset()` and `empty()`, because in your code you don't need to use both of them.

**[empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)**

> Determine whether a variable is considered to be empty. A variable is
>   considered empty if it does not exist or if its value equals FALSE.
>   empty() does not generate a warning if the variable does not exist.

```
function my_module_bibliographie_form_submit(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state){
  // Get the submitted entity.
  $key        = $form_state->getValue('field_key');
  $id_dossier = $form_state->getValue('field_dossier_reference');
  //You don't need isset().
  if (!empty($key) && !empty($id_dossier)) {
    kint($id_dossier[0]['target_id']);
    // Why you see this ugly ?
    $collection_key = $key[0]['value'];
   }
}
```

Comment: Yep !  thanks for fix. It's the only way to get value from field ?

Comment: @florian_drupal you can use $form_state->getValues()

Comment: Or something like that : `$node->get('field_date_derniere_modif')->getValue();`